# How to get all subnumbers of a number in haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to get all sub numbers of a number from a particular side.

In the case of the number 1234, the sub numbers from the left side are:

```
1, 12, 123, 1234
```

I implemented it with:

```
tail . inits $ show 1234
```

This way I get all the sub numbers in [[Char]] format.

```
["1","12","123","1234"]
```

I tried to convert them to Integer, with the following line.

```
map read . tail . inits $ show 1234
```

But I get the following error

```
[*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because the interpreter does not know what type you want back - try `map read . tail . inits $ show 1234 :: [Int]` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the interpreter does not know what type you want back

this will work:

```
λ> map read . tail . inits $ show 1234 :: [Int]
[1,12,123,1234]
```

of course you can just add a type-signature as well (most likely in your code file):

```
subnums :: Int -> [Int]
subnums = map read . tail . inits . show
```

---

in ghci:

```
λ> subnums 1234
[1,12,123,1234]
```

---

and a nice exercise can be to do this without `show`/`read`:

```
subnumbers :: Int -> [Int]
subnumbers 0 = []
subnumbers n =
  n : subnumbers (n `div` 10)
```

Can you solve the problem with the order here?

Comment: I had the later already implemented, but I wanted a nicer way. The main problem was that from the right side it becomes a bit more complicated, but with the usage of show and hide is almost the same for both left and right side.

Comment: it's not really more complicated (well the obvious *solution* will be less efficient but well ...) - anyway just a fun fact ;)

Answer (score 3):

A good approach is to use an **unfold**.  While a **fold** (variously known as *reduce*, *accumulate* or *aggregate* in other languages) can process a list of numbers (or values of other types) to compute a single result value, an unfold starts with a single value and expands it into a list of values according to a given function.  Let us examine the type of an unfold function:

```
Data.List.unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

We see that `unfoldr` take a function `(b -> Maybe (a, b)`, and a starting `b`.  The result is a `[a]`.  If the function evaluates to `Just (a, b)`, the `a` will be appended to the result, and the unfold recurses with the new `b`.  If the function evaluates to `Nothing`, the unfold is complete.

The function for your unfold is:

```
f :: Integral b => b -> Maybe (b, b)
f x = if x > 0 
  then Just (x, x `div` 10)  -- append x to result; continue with x/10
  else Nothing               -- x = 0; we're done
```

Now we can solve your problem without any of this `show` and `read` hackery:

```
λ> let f = (\x -> if x > 0 then Just (x, x `div` 10) else Nothing)
λ> reverse $ unfoldr f 1234
[1,12,123,1234]
```

Answer (score 2):

As Carsten [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138658/how-to-get-all-subnumbers-of-a-number-in-haskell#comment50288050_31138658), you need to give some indication of what type you want. This is because `read` is polymorphic in its result type. Until the compiler knows what type you want, it doesn't know what parser to use! An explicit type annotation is usually the way to go, but you might sometimes consider the function

```
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf x _ = x
```

---

### how to use this here

I see two obvious ways to use `asTypeOf` here:

```
λ> asTypeOf (map read . tail . inits $ show 1234) ([0] :: [Int])
[1,12,123,1234]
```

and

```
λ> map (asTypeOf read length) . tail . inits $ show 1234
[1,12,123,1234]
```

the first one seems hardly better at all and the second might be a bit tricky for beginners - but it works ;)

Why? Because `length` has type `[a] -> Int` and so the result type will be fixed to `Int`:

```
λ> :t (`asTypeOf` length)
(`asTypeOf` length) :: ([a] -> Int) -> [a] -> Int
```

which is just what we need for `read`

Please note that it's not important what `length` does - only it's type is important - any other function with an compatible signature would have worked as well (although I can come up only with `length` right now)

For example:

```
wantInt :: [a] -> Int
wantInt = undefined

λ> map (asTypeOf read wantInt) . tail . inits $ show 1234
[1,12,123,1234]
```

Comment: good idea but I think you should show how to use this exactly ;)

Comment: IDRIS `the` function would be really helpful here

Comment: @Carsten, thanks for the edit. Haskell doesn't need `the` so much because it allows terms as well as bindings to have type signatures.

Answer (score 1):

A working list comprehension solution:

```
subNums :: Int -> [Int]
subNums num = [read x | let str = show num, let size = length str, n <- [1 .. size], let x = take n str]

λ> subNums 1234
[1,12,123,1234]
```